# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' in OpenCV using Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

While training the dataset for faces, I'm using following code:

```
for imagePath in imagePaths:
            faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
            faceNP = np.array(faceImg,'uint8')
            ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath[-1]).split('.')[1])
            #ID1 = (char, count)
            #ID=int(ID1.split('.')[1])
            faces.append(faceImg)
            IDs.append(ID)
            cv2.imshow('training',faceNP)
            cv2.waitKey(10)
    return IDs, faces
```

For this I'm getting following error:
    ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath[-1]).split('.')[1])
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if `imagePath = "path1/path2/img.jpg"`,
then 
`imagePath[-1]` returns `'g'`.
os.path.split(imagePath[-1])
returns
('','g')

So, you can't apply split to the above tuple.

You are using split twice: first with `os.path.split` and then with `.split`